# Ejecutar codigo Java en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-netbeans

Quiero ejecutar este código de Java en el IDE NetBeans

```
public class ClassTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            System.out.print("Valor de i: " + i);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me sale el siguiente error "Command execution failed" cuando intento ejecutar el código de Java

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está diciendo el programa, es que no encuentra la clase principal, si lo que muestras es todo lo que hay en tu archivo, te falta colocar el "package classtest;" esta sentencia va antes que nada, y el archivo que creaste, debe estar en  "/nombreDelPrograma/src/classtest".
La mejor manera es crear el programa desde NetBeans, luego creas la clase, y NetBeans se encarga de todo lo demás... espero haberte ayudado!.